# When do stations move to a new location?

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

In the Civilization Wikia, on the [Stations Page](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Station_(CivBE)) it indicates that:

> Stations may land on the planet at any time. They are looking to trade with the players, and if nobody comes forward within a given period of time, **they pack their belongings and move to a new location on the planet.** Only one city per each civilization can trade with a given Station simultaneously.

But I haven't found anything on how much that period of time is before they leave.

Is there a confirmation of how long it takes? Also, is there a way to find out if nobody else has traded with them?

Comment: I think depends on the speed setting of the game. I have observed this behaviour myself, and although I cant give an accurate answer I would say its around the 50 turns mark.

Answer (score 2):

Stations will disappear after 45 turns without people sending trade routes (scaling with game speed). The game will try to maintain 2 Stations per Player, so relatively shortly after a station has withdrawn the game will try to spawn a new one (Stations CAN spawn again after they have withdrawn/been destroyed) as long as there is enough space between cities available.

Some people claim that it is 30 turns - but they may have been on different game speeds. Generally assume it is minimum of 30 and max around 45.

There is not really a way to see who is trading with them unless you are watching for trade vessels to and from the station.

Overall there is not a ton of documented information about stations mostly because of the mixed response the game got - and now with Civ VI out it has been largely abandoned.